# jpa OneToOne relations with more than one table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have these two tables with OneToOne relation :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Event")
public class Event implements Serializable {

@Id
private String id;

@JoinColumn(name = "ID")
@OneToOne
@MapsId
public OutgoingEventRequest outgoingEventRequest;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Outgoing_Event_Request")
public class OutgoingEventRequest implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
private String id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "outgoingEventRequest")
private Event event;

}
```

This works fine , but I want to add another OneToOne table to Event, so Event will have OneToOne relations with two (and maybe later – more) tables , and every time use the id of the relavent table , so some recored will be with the is of Outgoing_Event_Request table and some will have the id of another table and so on ..
How can I do it ?

Comment: Unless all the entities linked to Event are sub-entities of a single entity, that doesn't make much sense: several of these entities could have the same ID, thus violating the PK contraint of the Event table. And even if they don't, nobody could tell, by just having the ID of the entity, which of the entity types it identifies. Is it the ID of an OutgoingEventRequest, of an IngoinEventRequest, of some other entity? So this design, both from a JPA and from a relational database point of view, doesn't make much sense.

Comment: what if I will add a column in EVENT that tell what is the record type ?

Comment: That still wouldn't work if several linked entities happen to have the same ID. And you still wouldn't be able to use several OneToOne all mapped as ID anyway. Are you sure all the linked entities aren't in fact sub-entities of the same base entity class?